# How can I redirect Ballerina logs to a file while still displaying it on the terminal

Tags: ballerina

I want to save the logs of my [Ballerina](http://ballerina.io) program to a file while displaying it on the terminal, so I used the following command:

```
$ ballerina run sample.balx |tee out.log
```

However, this doesn't write anything on the out.log file even though the program executes successfully and shows logs on the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The above command is to write `stdout` to a file. However, [Ballerina writes its logs to the `stderr` stream](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/log/index.html). so you have to use the below command.

```
ballerina run sample.balx 2>&1 | tee out.log
```

This command redirects `stderr` to `stdout` so `tee` can echo it to the display and the file.